# What does this restaurant sign in episode 5 say?

Tags: michiko-to-hatchin

In episode 5 of *Michiko & Hatchin*, Michiko and Hatchin go to what looks like a restaurant so that Michiko can ask about Satoshi's current whereabouts. This sign appears on the exterior wall of it.

[image: restaurant sign]

What is written on this sign? I think it's supposed to contain Latin characters — I can see an A and an R, maybe an S — but the whole of it is so distorted that I can't make sense of it at all. It's also possible that this is something in Portuguese (keeping with the rest of the setting), which isn't a language I know either.

Comment: Note that in the shot where you see the older brother guy with the pot the letters T and A are visible. Part of the third is visible, one can assume it to be a R or maybe P as the character is capitalized and straight. Last three characters seem to be RAY. One assumes all the characters are capital letters.